# Bootstrap Table loading progressbar overlay

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an Table somewhere in my HTML and an Pagination that loads the next page with ajax. 
While loading the data i want to overlay an div with an Bootstrap progress-bar.

```js
function loadingTable(divID) {

 var html = " <div class='table-loading-overlay'>"
  + " <div class='table-loading-inner'>"
  + "<div class=\"col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4\">"
  + "<div class=\"progress\"> "
  + "<div class=\"progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-streit active\" role=\"progressbar\" aria-valuenow=\"100\" aria-valuemin=\"0\" aria-valuemax=\"100\" style=\"width: 100%\">"
  + "        <span class=\"sr-only\">Loading...</span>"
  + "    </div>"
  + "    </div>"
  + " </div>"
  + " </div>"
  + " </div>";
 $('#' + divID).append(html);
}
function prevPage(){}
function nextPage(){}
```

```css
.table-loading-inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.table-loading-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
    background:  #000000;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
  <div id="userList">
   <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
                  <td>Test 1</td>
                  <td>active</td>
                  </tr>                      
     <tr>
                  <td>Test 2</td>
                  <td>active</td>
                  </tr>                      
     <tr>
                  <td>Test 3</td>
                  <td>active</td>
                  </tr>
     <tr>
                  <td>Test 4</td>
                  <td>active</td>
                  </tr>
     <tr>
                  <td>Test 5</td>
                  <td>active</td>
                  </tr> 
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <div>
    <span style="float:right;"> 10 Users <i class="fa fa-list"></i></span>
   </div>
   <div class="paginator">
      <span class="btn btn-default" onclick="prevPage();loadingTable('userList');"> prev</span>
      <span class="btn btn-default"  onclick="nextPage();loadingTable('userList');">next</span>
   </div>
  </div>
```

How do I get the `table-loading-overlay` over the table?
As the Table can be everywhere in the HTML I can't use absolute position...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give the parent div a  fixed position if you don't want to use an absolute positioned div. Which should actually work as well. It should not matter where the table is in the document.

Here is your example with a fixed positioned parent.

```js
function loadingTable(divID) {

  var html = " <div class='table-loading-overlay'>"
  + " <div class='table-loading-inner'>"
  + "<div class=\"col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4\">"
  + "<div class=\"progress\"> "
  + "<div class=\"progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-streit active\" role=\"progressbar\" aria-valuenow=\"100\" aria-valuemin=\"0\" aria-valuemax=\"100\" style=\"width: 100%\">"
  + "        <span class=\"sr-only\">Loading...</span>"
  + "    </div>"
  + "    </div>"
  + " </div>"
  + " </div>"
  + " </div>";

  $('#' + divID).append(html);
  $('.table-loading-overlay').css('height', $('#' + divID).height() + 'px');
  $('.table-loading-inner').css('padding-top', ($('#' + divID).height() / 2) + 'px');
}
function prevPage(){}
function nextPage(){}
```

```css
.table-loading-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background:  #000000;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.table-loading-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="userList">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td>active</td>
      </tr>                      
      <tr>
        <td>Test 2</td>
        <td>active</td>
      </tr>                      
      <tr>
        <td>Test 3</td>
        <td>active</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test 4</td>
        <td>active</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test 5</td>
        <td>active</td>
      </tr> 
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <span style="float:right;"> 10 Users <i class="fa fa-list"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="paginator">
    <span class="btn btn-default" onclick="prevPage();loadingTable('userList');"> prev</span>
    <span class="btn btn-default"  onclick="nextPage();loadingTable('userList');">next</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well that's working, but i would like to have the overlay just over the table and not over the complete page...

Comment: You can easily set the fixed positioned parents height using jQuery's `css`  method. You are already passing in the tables parent `id` to your function, so you can do pretty much anything to the overlay to make it look like you want. I have edited my answer. But why don't you want to set the *userList* div to position relative and have the overlay positioned absolute? Just curios.